# GSP Exception thrown for "Method code too large"?

Tags: java, grails, gsp

I am getting the exception below when I try to access my Grails application. What is the problem?

> Error | 2019-10-10 16:24:39,538 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR
>   pages.GroovyPagesTemplateEngine - Compilation error compiling GSP
>   [C__praveen_HOTS_grails_app_views_main_monetarystatusdet_gsp]:startup
>   failed: General error during class generation: Method code too large!
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Method code too large! at
>   groovyjarjarasm.asm.MethodWriter.a(Unknown Source) at
>   groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassWriter.toByteArray(Unknown Source) at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$15.call(CompilationUnit.java:796)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$15.call(CompilationUnit.java:811)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$15.call(CompilationUnit.java:811)
>   at

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We'll need more information to properly help you: what have you tried so far, what specifically is going wrong, and do you have a minimal working example of the issue? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [Creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your GSP has too much code within it and exceeds the 65K (or so) lines per script block. The "workaround" is to add a comment in the GSP to break up the script block size like this:

```
<% 
  // just a comment 
%>
```

Placing that somewhere in the middle or in several spots in your GSP file will resolve this issue.

Comment: This didn't solve the problem for me.